# How to run php with XAMPP's apache?

Tags: php, css, xampp, localhost

So I have a .php file, I wanted to see it's output.
So, I open my xampp. I press the start button 'start' for apache. I go to my browser and type localhost/filename
The problem is, instead of seeing the file directory of my computer. I saw the output of my php. I thought it was something that I shouldn't be concerned about but then when I do some changes to my code, and I refresh my output on the browser nothing happens like nothing changes even though I erase the .css file in my php code.

[image: This is the image]

See the link and yeah, I type the directory but I was directed to my output in instant and my apache doesn't work like this like a month ago. Should I update my apache? or what?

**This is xampp for windows**

Comment: XAMPP for Windows? Use the XAMPP control panel, check phpinfo() output. see https://netbeans.apache.org/kb/docs/php/configure-php-environment-windows.html for more.

Comment: yup this is xampp for windows

Comment: please be more clear, why are you expecting to *see the file directory of your computer?* Perhaps delete the `index.php` or `index.html` file

Comment: If you want to see the directory listing instead of the output of the php code, you'll want to enable directory listing in XAMPP. You'll also want to remove index.php, index.html from the directives settings in configuration. But why would you want to see the directory listing?

Comment: I want to see the directory so that It's easy for me to see other files that stored in my folder. And I can easily open it just click "Open in the new Window"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DID YOU **open** XAMPP Control Panel

DID YOU **'Start'** Apache, **'Start'** MYSQL

DID YOU click **'Explorer'** (right side of window)

DID YOU **delete** the default *index.php* file

DID YOU type in your browser **'localhost'** and press ENTER?

Comment: I didn't click the Explorer button